# send a JSON data object to the server using Javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

Im conding in php and would like to send the information on the calender to the controller. I think my MVC is set up correctly and i get a status 200 that the data is sent as an object (see photo) but when i want to receive it in the controller i keep getting NULL. My project does not have a .htacess and uses a basic router. I run everthing form my docker container. The idea is click a tile and sent the object information to the controller so i can add it to a shoppingcart. Any help is appreciated

this is the code that i was trying in my javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelectorAll('.event').forEach(function(eventElement) {
    eventElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var eventDetails = {
            name: this.getAttribute('data-name'),
            startTime: this.getAttribute('data-start-time'),
            endTime: this.getAttribute('data-end-time')
        };
        // Send AJAX request to the server
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/jazz');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(eventDetails);
                    console.log('Request successful');
                } else {
                    console.error('Request failed');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(eventDetails));
    });
  });
});
```

This is my controller where i want to receive the information but the vardump is empty and it does not go in the if-statement

```
OUTPUT - var_dump($requestData) = string(0) ""
OUTPUT - var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) = string(3) "GET"
OUTPUT - var_dump($selectedEventData) = NULL
OUTPUT - var_dump($_REQUEST) = array(4) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) 
"5c37a82703acc9f86f54c3817f08c4e9" ["pma_lang"]=> string(2) "nl" 
["phpMyAdmin"]=> string(32) "18b3f28efd9ffb94e2c3a28ae292819f" 
["pmaUser-1"]=> string(60)  
"JNBvWJn0SxdqeVHqQN1vIu7Hx4P9BdLusicXILkrWFCTKGhrT1VLLIUcFxw=" }
```

jazzcontroller.php:

```
    $requestData =  file_get_contents("php://input");
    var_dump($requestData);
 
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    $selectedEventData = json_decode($requestData, true);
    var_dump($selectedEventData);
    if ($selectedEventData) {
        var_dump($selectedEventData);
        $selectedEventDetails = new EventMusic();
        $selectedEventDetails->getArtist()->setName($selectedEventData['name']);
        $selectedEventDetails->setStartTime($selectedEventData['startTime']);
        $selectedEventDetails->setEndTime($selectedEventData['endTime']);
```

this is my router
<?php

```
namespace Routers;
use Exception;
```

class PatternRouter
{

```
private function stripParameters($uri)
{
    if (str_contains($uri, '?')) {

        $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    }
    return $uri;
}

public function route($uri)
{
    // Check if there's an api request
    $api = false;
    if (str_starts_with($uri, "api/")) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 4);
        $api = true;
    }

    //Check if there's an request to the CMS
    $cms = false;
    if (str_starts_with($uri, "cms/")) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 4);
        $cms = true;
    }

    // Set default controller & method
    $defaultcontroller = 'home';
    $defaultmethod = 'index';

    // Ignore query parameters
    $uri = $this->stripParameters($uri);

    // Read controller & method names from URI
    $explodedUri = explode('/', $uri);

    if (!isset($explodedUri[0]) || empty($explodedUri[0])) {
        $explodedUri[0] = $defaultcontroller;
    }
    $controllerName = $explodedUri[0] . "controller";

    if (!isset($explodedUri[1]) || empty($explodedUri[1])) {
        $explodedUri[1] = $defaultmethod;
    }
    $methodName = $explodedUri[1];

    // Require the file with the controller class
    $className = "Controllers\\" . $controllerName;

    if ($api) {
        $className = "ApiControllers\\" . $controllerName;
    }

    // Dynamically call controller & method
    try {
        $controllerObj = new $className;
        $controllerObj->{$methodName}();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(404);
        // die();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks again for all the feedback, I kept trying with no result e.g. changing the javascript code to send the data differently (without sending object) but no luck yet. I will keep trying

Comment: the code you posted looks like it should work - so the problem may be in the code you haven't posted

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong with this either. Please check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains inside your controller there.

Comment: `the vardump`...which one? Try to be specific please (or to remove irrelevant things from your code!).

Comment: Also did you check your Network tool to ensure there's no redirection taking place (e.g. from POST to GET) which might explain the absence of any data?

Comment: Thanks for the update. `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) = string(3) "GET"` strongly indicates the presence of a redirect which is changing your POST request to a GET. Either that or you're somehow viewing the response to a completely different request into the /jazz controller, which is unrelated to your XHR request. Specifically when, and where, are you viewing these var_dump outputs? For them to relate to the response to your XHR request you would need to be using your browser's Developer Tools to monitor the XHR request in the Network tab, clicking on the XHR request and then Response

Comment: Thanks for helping, So I was trying to display these vardumps at 2 different moments in my jazzcontroller. 1 is before the page is loaded with require __DIR__ . '/../view/jazzpage/jazzhome/index.php'; and the other one is after clicking on a event in my calendar, to see if i would get the data in my controller. So as suggested i was checking the response and i got this in response array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "Chris Allen"
  ["startTime"]=>
  string(8) "21:00:00"
  ["endTime"]=>
  string(8) "22:00:00"
}

Comment: So obviously the `require DIR . '/../view/jazzpage/jazzhome/index.php` call will not show you any data, because it's loaded as part of a GET request to a different page, there's no data posted to it. So that makes sense in terms of the output you saw. The second report you've given, from the Response tab of the network tool seems accurate. So I would suggest that your XHR request is actually working correctly. The only problem seems to be that you didn't debug it properly.

Comment: Thanks i completely overlooked that. Sorry for rookie mistake. So please correct me if i am wrong, but i could just send the information to a different file instead of the same one and access the data there right?

Comment: Yes you can send an xhr request to any url you like

Comment: Okay so to verify if I made some changes and can you verify if i understand the concept. The data could not be shown because the page is part of a get request instead of a post. But are not all the url part of the get request. Like for example if i made a testcontroller and the url would then be /test without the require etc, then it would still be a get request right.? Sorry for all the questions Im trying to understand the concept so i code a good solution.

Comment: It's the 2020's, time to learn how to use Fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Whether something is a GET request depends on whether the client makes a GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD or whatever else request to it. These are all types of HTTP request. You can send any of those types of request to any URL. So if you have a URL like `https://example.com/test` I can send a GET request to it, or  POST request, or anything else, all to the same URL. Requests sent by different methods may be received and processed differently by the server, depending what rules/code/logic it has in place for responding.

Comment: It sounds like you are lacking some basic background knowledge about the mechanics of the web and HTTP. You should read a guide such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview to get up to speed. If you don't understand the fundamentals of how something works then it's very difficult to correctly write code which utilitises it or relies on it. Don't try to run before you can walk. (I am always frustrated when you find people being taught "coding" without any kind of background in computer science to accompany it - it's usually doomed to failure, or at least mediocrity).

Comment: Well thanks for all the information, I will continue on with this with my new knowledge

Comment: I fixed it thanks for all the help. My solution was just to send it to a different url like xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/jazz/post'); and put that function in my controller 
    public function post(){
$requestData =  file_get_contents("php://input"); and it works now. Thanks for all the support

Comment: Yep that will stop it complaining about missing data during a GET request to the original url. Glad you found a solution you're happy with